# Reading from txt.file to linked list, need help correcting code

Tags: c

I'm having problems getting a proper output, the list gets messed up.

1.I've been told to break my while loop down in smaller parts would help, but i can't seem to get it right.
problem: a number "1" pops up between some of the colums when printing, further down the code it's replaced with "-858993460". ***Why is this happening?***

My goal: "robot" "Termintortyp" "idnr" \n

AKA: "Termintor" "T-800/T-1000" "1-100"

2.I also want to add an errorcheck:

If an error appears-> print an error message and then the code should continue till the linked list has run out. example: between 11 and 12th line it says "FEL FEL FEL" or row 16 "_____TERMINATOR T-1000 16".If the problem can be identified while reading the txt.file into the linked list and somehow replace that "incorrect termintor"-line with an error message would solve my problem, but i don't know how to do it proper. ***Any suggestions?***

Appreciating all the help i can get!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
struct Link {
char robot[12];
char terminatortyp[10];
int idnr;
struct Link *next;
};
typedef struct Link Link;
Link *first = NULL;

int main(void) {
int antal = 0;
Link a;
FILE *tsin = fopen("textfil1R.txt", "r");
if (tsin == NULL) {
    printf("Kunde inte läsa filen 'textfil.txt'.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

Link *temp;

while (fgets(a.robot, sizeof a.robot, tsin) != NULL)
{
    temp = malloc(sizeof(Link));
    strcpy(temp->robot, a.robot);

    fgets(a.terminatortyp, sizeof a.terminatortyp, tsin);
    strcpy(temp->terminatortyp, a.terminatortyp);


        fscanf(tsin, "%d", &a.idnr);
        temp->idnr = a.idnr;

        temp->next = first;
        first = temp;

        ++antal;

    }
fclose(tsin);


    Link *p = first;
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        //printf("%d\n", p->idnr);
        printf("%s", p->robot);
        printf("%s", p->terminatortyp);
        printf("%d\n", p->idnr);
        p = p->next;

    }
    printf("%d", antal);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

The textfile im reading this from:

```
TERMINATOR T-800 1
TERMINATOR T-1000 2
TERMINATOR T-800 3
TERMINATOR T-800 4
TERMINATOR T-1000 5
TERMINATOR T-800 6
TERMINATOR T-800 7
TERMINATOR T-800 8
TERMINATOR T-1000 9
TERMINATOR T-800 10
TORMONUTTUR T-800 101
TERMINATOR T-800 11
FEL FEL FEL
TERMINATOR T-1000 12
TERMINATOR T-800 13
TERMINATOR T-800 14
TERMINATOR           T-800         15
       TERMINATOR T-1000 16
TERMINATOR T-800 17                       
TERMINATOR T-800 18
TERMINATOR T-1000 19
TERMINATOR T-800 20
TERMINATOR T-800 21
TERMINATOR T-800 22
TERMINATOR T-1000 23
TERMINATOR T-800 24
TERMINATOR T-800 25
TERMINATOR T-1000 26
TERMINATOR T-800 27
TERMINATOR T-800 28
TERMINATOR T-800 29
TERMINATOR T-1000 30
TERMINATOR T-800 31
TERMINATOR T-800 32
TERMINATOR T-1000 33
TERMINATOR T-800 34
TERMINATOR T-800 35
TERMINATOR T-800 36
TERMINATOR T-1000 37
TERMINATOR T-800 38
TERMINATOR T-800 39
TERMINATOR T-1000 40
TERMINATOR T-800 41
TERMINATOR T-800 42
TERMINATOR T-800 43
TERMINATOR T-1000 44
TERMINATOR T-800 45
TERMINATOR T-800 46
TERMINATOR T-1000 47
TERMINATOR T-800 48
TERMINATOR T-800 49
TERMINATOR T-800 50
TERMINATOR T-1000 51
TERMINATOR T-800 52
TERMINATOR T-800 53
TERMINATOR T-1000 54
TERMINATOR T-800 55
TERMINATOR T-800 56
TERMINATOR T-800 57
TERMINATOR T-1000 58
TERMINATOR T-800 59
TERMINATOR T-800 60
TERMINATOR T-1000 61
TERMINATOR T-800 62
TERMINATOR T-800 63
TERMINATOR T-800 64
TERMINATOR T-1000 65
TERMINATOR T-800 66
TERMINATOR T-800 67
TERMINATOR T-1000 68
TERMINATOR T-800 69
TERMINATOR T-800 70
TERMINATOR T-800 71
TERMINATOR T-1000 72
TERMINATOR T-800 73
TERMINATOR T-800 74
TERMINATOR T-1000 75
TERMINATOR T-800 76
TERMINATOR T-800 77
TERMINATOR T-800 78
TERMINATOR T-1000 79
TERMINATOR T-800 80
TERMINATOR T-800 81
TERMINATOR T-1000 82
TERMINATOR T-800 83
TERMINATOR T-1001 84
TERMINATOR T-800 85
TERMINATOR T-1000 86
TERMINATOR T-800 87
TERMINATOR T-800 88
TERMINATOR T-1000 89
TERMINATOR T-800 90
TERMINATOR T-800 91
TERMINATOR T-800 92
TERMINATOR T-1000 93
TERMINATOR T-850 94
TERMINATOR T-800 95
TERMINATOR T-1000 96
TERMINATOR T-800 97
TERMINATOR T-800 98
TERMINATOR T-800 99
TERMINATOR T-1000 100
```

Comment: Note that your list is a _stack_, last-in, first-out.

Comment: when outputting an error message, it should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.   It is always a good idea when outputting an error message that is about a problem indicated by a system function that the displayed output include the reason the system thinks the call to the function failed.  The best way to do that is with `perror()`  although `fprintf( stderr, "..." );` will also do the job if the returned value from `strerror()` is also output.  So this line: `printf("Kunde inte läsa filen 'textfil.txt'.\n");` should be: `perror("Kunde inte läsa filen 'textfil.txt'");`

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the function: `fgets()` will also include an trailing newline in the input, so that newline should (usually) be replaced with a '\0'.  One way to do that is: char *newline = NULL;  if( NULL != (newline = strchr( a.robot, '\n' ) ) { *newline = '\0'; }`

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, including `fscanf()`, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: this code: `temp->next = first;
        first = temp;` results in a circular entry I.E. it points to itself.  it also, on subsequent entries, places the new entry at the beginning of the list.

Comment: this statement: `while (p != NULL)` will always be true because a circular list was created, no non of the entries contains a NULL `next` field

Comment: this function: `getch();` is non standard.  much better to use: `int ch; while( (ch = getchar() ) != EOF && '\n' != ch );  getchar();`

Comment: However, the function: `fgets()` does not stop at a space char, so the input will be corrupted.  Suggest declaring an array that is long enough to hold the longest line in the file, use fgets() to read the line from the file into that array, then use `strtok()` to extract each item in the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fgets()` to read a *line*, not a word.

```
char line[100];
while (fgets(line, sizeof line, tsin) != NULL) {
```

Now parse the line.  Use `%n` to save the offset of the scan - if it got that far.  Be sure to limit the maximum width of characters acceptable for the members.  Additional checks are possible.  This will get you started.

```
  struct Link entry = { 0 }; // zero fill members
  int n = 0;
  int lead;
  sscanf(line," %n%11s%9s%d %n",&lead, entry.robot, entry.terminatortyp, &entry.idnr, &n);
  // All specifiers scanned and no extra junk? 
  if (n == 0 || line[n]) {
    printf("Bad line <%s>\n", line);
    continue;
  }
  if (lead > 0) {
    printf("leading spaces <%s>\n", line);
    continue;
  }
```

Add sanity checks on members as desired.

```
  if (entry.idnr < 1 || entry.idnr > 9999) {
    printf("Bad index <%s>\n", line);
    continue;
  }
```

Success, now allocate

```
  struct Link *node = malloc(sizeof *node);
  if (node == NULL) {
    printf("Out of memory at line <%s>\n", line);
    break;
  }
  *node = entry;
  node->next = first;
  first = node;
}
```

> Any suggestions?

@imanoob, du är inte en noob

Answer (score 1):

You are using `fgets` as if it would read in a single string until the next whitespace. Yet `fgets` reads in a complete line until it detects new line character `'\n'` or reaches the end of the file.

So after statement `fgets(a.robot, sizeof a.robot, tsin)`, the value of `a.robot` is probably `TERMINATOR T-800 17\n` and not `TERMINATOR`. This leads to a buffer overflow on the one hand, and with repeated `fgets` statements in the loop you actually read in complete lines into the current `temp` object.

```
while (fscanf(tsin, "%11s %9s %d", a.robot, a.terminatortyp, &a.idnr) == 3)
{
    temp = malloc(sizeof(Link));
    strcpy(temp->robot, a.robot);
    strcpy(temp->terminatortyp, a.terminatortyp);
    temp->idnr = a.idnr;

    temp->next = first;
    first = temp;

    ++antal;
}
```

Note the maximum field width specifier `%11s`, which makes sure that at most 11 characters are read in (+ one additional string termination character), such that the scan fits into a buffer of size 12. Confer, for example, [cppreference/scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf):

> %11s: If width specifier is used, matches up to width or until the first
>   whitespace character, whichever appears first. Always stores a null
>   character in addition to the characters matched (so the argument array
>   must have room for at least width+1 characters)

Comment: Off by one: `char robot[12];
char terminatortyp[10]; ... "%12s %10s %d"` --> `"%11s %9s %d"`

Comment: Rather than `strcpy(temp->robot, a.robot);
    strcpy(temp->terminatortyp, a.terminatortyp);
    temp->idnr = a.idnr; `, could use `*temp = a;` or the like.

Comment: @chux: right, thanks! adapted the answer and added a short description for the width-specifier. Concerning `strcpy` vs `*temp=a`: thanks for the valuable comment. Just wanted to not change OPs code for other aspects than initially asked, so I did not add it to the answer.